# Using jQuery and CSS hover-states on the same element

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-hover

I'm using a mix of both jQuery and CSS hover states on the same class that's assigned to a list item.

The jQuery is replacing text on hover. The CSS is hiding a div and show an image on hover.

My problem is that the jQuery hover event is causing the CSS hover to not work and I'm not quite sure why.

**Here's the list item that I'm implementing both the CSS Hover and jQuery hover on**

```
 <div class="list">
    <ul class="projectList">
    <li class="projectImage1"><a href="">Philomena Kwao<span><img src="helene images/philomena.jpg" alt="" height="580" width="370" /></span></a></li>
 </div
```

**Here's the CSS allowing me to hide a section and display an image simultaneously**

```
.list:hover + section.container {
  display: none;
}
```

**Here's the jQuery hover event thats replacing the text on hover**

```
    // Text replace! 
$('.projectImage1').hover(function() {     
           $(this).text("Article");
         },
        function() {
         $(this).text("Philomena Kwao");
 });
```

I've also made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/jordan_miguel/pen/qmypNW) to illustrate the issue.

Hover over the first list item, then hover over the second list item to clearly see whats happening.

Comment: `element.text("Hello")` deletes **all of the content** of that element, and replaces it with *"Hello"*. Your image isn't showing up because it's been removed from the page.

Comment: @Santi thanks that makes its a lot clearer. Is there a method you would suggest to work around this?

Comment: Wrap the text you want to replace in a `<span class="name-text">`, and do `$(this).find(".name-text").text("Article")`. This way, you're only replacing the contents of the name element, not the entire list item. [**Example**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwLLmL)

Comment: @Santi could you quickly demonstrate this via codepen? Doesn't seem to be working for me, I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Sure. [**Here it is**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwLLmL). Also, it seems like your current method is going to have you manually doing this for every link, which could get super tedious. Consider instead using a slightly more advanced technique: Apply the hover event to *all* your `<li>` elements, not each one by ID. Put a `data-hover-text` attribute on them, and then you can display the text using `$(this).find("name-text").text($(this).data("hover-text"));` - Again, this is slightly more advanced, but much better in the long run.

Comment: [An example to demonstrate my suggestion](https://jsfiddle.net/01ss1srr/1/) - Notice how I have one JavaScript event that works for all `<li>` elements. It looks at the `data-initial-text` and `data-new-text` attributes instead of hard-coding an event for each and every one!

Comment: wow this is super efficient, I was dreading doing it for every link. Thanks for explaining how this works. Much appreciated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144401/discussion-between-jordan-miguel-and-santi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're actually overwriting everything in your li.

So here is your HTML before your hover

```
<div class="list">
  <h2>Writing - </h2>
  <ul class="projectList">
    <li class="projectImage1" id="projectImage1-hover">
      <a href="#">Philomena Kwao
        <span>
          <img src="helene images/philomena.jpg" alt="" height="580" width="370" />
        </span>
      </a>
      </li>
      <li class="projectImage2">
        <a href="#">Jorja Smith
          <span>
            <img src="helene images/jorja.jpg" alt="" height="450" width="450" />
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When you hover with `$('#projectImage1-hover').hover()` you actually are re-writing the contents of `#projectImage1-hover`.

So it looks like this after your hover:

```html
<div class="list">
  <h2>Writing - </h2>
  <ul class="projectList">
    <li class="projectImage1" id="projectImage1-hover">
       Article
    </li>
    <li class="projectImage2">
        <a href="#">Jorja Smith
          <span>
            <img src="helene images/jorja.jpg" alt="" height="450" width="450" />
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And then it looks like this as you stop hovering:

```html
<div class="list">
  <h2>Writing - </h2>
  <ul class="projectList">
    <li class="projectImage1" id="projectImage1-hover">
      Philomena Kwao
    </li>
    <li class="projectImage2">
      <a href="#">Jorja Smith
        <span>
          <img src="helene images/jorja.jpg" alt="" height="450" width="450" />
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Using this code below, take note of the `<span class="name">Philomena Kwao</span>` as this is what will be changed by the javascript.

Your jQuery's context matters when selecting elements, especially because you're currently replacing all of the children of `$('#projectImage1-hover')` with only the text.

```js
// Project hover animations 
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Text replace! 
  $('#projectImage1-hover').hover(function() {
      // store $(this).text() in a variable     
      $(this).find('.name').text("Article");
    },
    function() {
      // assign it back here
      $(this).find('.name').text("Philomena Kwao");
    });

});
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <h2>Writing - </h2>
  <ul class="projectList">
    <li class="projectImage1" id="projectImage1-hover">
      <a href="#">
        <span class="name">Philomena Kwao</span>
        <span>
          <img src="helene images/philomena.jpg" alt="" height="580" width="370" />
        </span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is a codepen with Philomena Kwao now working: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KmBBLy

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain what I was doing wrong. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

your call to .text() is clobbering all elements contained in your list item. do this instead: add a span around your text and select it directly.

```
 <div class="list">
    <ul class="projectList">
    <li class="projectImage1"><a href=""><span class="hover-text">Philomena Kwao</span><span><img src="helene images/philomena.jpg" alt="" height="580" width="370" /></span></a></li>
 </div>


$('.projectImage1').hover(function() {     
           $('.projectImage1 hover-text').text("Article");
         },
        function() {
         $('.projectImage1 hover-text').text("Philomena Kwao");
 });
```